# Should one signal a post on Stack Overflow with the flag system in case of bad tagging?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I stumbled on some questions on Stack Overflow that would benefit from retagging. How do I interact with them? Do I wait for sufficient reputation to edit the tagging? Or do I signal the post to a moderator; this solution feels like a waste of time for them, so I'm really not sure.

What's the official word here?

Comment: Post the questions as examples here, they will be fixed pretty quickly then. ;)

Comment: i don't remember the specific question, it was one question about mvc that was specifically directed at asp-net.mvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options, depending on the circumstances:

- Gain enough rep and site experience to retag on your own (this would be ideal, of course).
- Leave the questions alone. If the questions are relatively new (less than a day or two old), then there's a good chance of someone with enough rep will come along and retag. If the questions are older than that, try one of the other options.
- Leave an @-directed comment to a user involved in the question who has enough rep to retag (or the original author, who can always retag their own questions). For this to work, you probably want to pick the most active user who's involved. Most people on the sites are very friendly as long as you ask nicely.
- Post a support question here on Meta. This is usually done only for larger requests where a moderator needs to be involved (there could be thousands of questions involved in a retagging), but I don't see a problem with posting if you have only a handful of questions that need fixing, particularly if you need help determining which tags to put on a question. It's better to run it by the community than to do it incorrectly! There are enough people here with enough rep on all the sites to take care of most requests without moderator intervention. One thing I *wouldn't* do, though, is post a new question for each individual question request, as that would get a bit annoying... I'd say post at least 4-5 questions-in-need-of-retagging at a time, and you can edit your Meta question if you come across any others that need attention.
- Directly flag individual questions for moderator attention. As you hinted, this should be used *only as a last resort*. Most of the time, this happens if a migrated question (or, more precisely, a *locked* question) needs to be retagged. Since you're just starting out on the site, you most likely won't come across this situation.

Also, thanks for coming to Meta to ask this question.

Comment: I especially like the "@-directed comment" method. Though indeed, gaining enough rep should be the best way to take.

Answer (score 4):

Just leave it to someone with enough rep; usually it "gets fixed" quickly.

Alternately, the rep limit for retags is 500, you should be able to get there relatively quickly; then you could retag it yourself.